# Removing letters entered in input on keydown removes numbers instead?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a telephone input that updates with dashes on keydown, when a user enters a letter I'm trying to instantly remove that character entry by using `this.value.slice(0, -1)` but this removes the last number instead. Would anyone be able to explain how this is happening?

**JS**

```
var isNumber = validateNumber(event);

    if (isNumber) {
        if (inputLength == 3) {
            this.value = this.value + '-';
        } else if (inputLength == 7) {
            this.value = this.value + '-';
        }
    } else {
        var newValue = this.value.slice(0, -1);
        this.value = newValue;
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cm803xuu/4/

Comment: Keep in mind what you are trying to accomplish is very difficult. What if I paste i. Text? Your event won't even fire.

Comment: I'm used to use http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin to do masks.

Comment: Afraid it's got to be straight up vanilla JS for this one

Comment: http://bankfacil.github.io/vanilla-masker/

Comment: add `event.preventDefault()` at the right place: http://jsfiddle.net/cm803xuu/12/

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's all because of the event type you use. 'Keydown' is dispatched before actual change occurs. So you may try to use `event.preventDefault();` right when a wrong character is detected.

Answer (score 0):

There were two changes that I made to your jsfiddle to get the code to operate at expected:

- switch to the `keyup` event.  I think your first problem is that the letter hasnt been appended yet to `value` when your code executes.
- You were using the wrong arguments for the `slice` function.  Consider these two options:
- `this.value.slice(0, this.value.length-1)`
- `this.value.slice(0, -1)`

The second options will take the entire string (`value`) all except the last character.  That's how the `-1` index operates.

Here's the updated function:

```
telInput.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    var inputValue = this.value,
        inputLength = inputValue.length;

    var val = validateNumber(event);

   if (val) {
       if (inputLength == 3) {
           this.value = this.value + '-';
        } else if (inputLength == 7) {
           this.value = this.value + '-';
        }
    } else {
        var newValue = this.value.slice(0, this.value.length-1);
        this.value = newValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: if I change to keyup I can easily skip by adding dashes if I type the numbers in really quickly, any idea how to avoid that? http://jsfiddle.net/cm803xuu/11/